# What versions of python does pip support?

Tags: python, pip

What is the minimum python version required for pip? A look at the release notes shows that as of version 1.3.1 or so the minimum required version was Python 2.5, but I haven't seen any further notes that indicate support for Python 2.5 was dropped, so it's a question in my mind. I probably am just being stupid and missed something obvious.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#python-os-support

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't really matter. There's little python software that's being actively developed for anything older than python 2.6.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: That should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Well, just a link makes a poor answer and I don't have much useful info to add :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: there's nothing more useful than the official source. If you don't do it, I'm gonna write that answer :)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Feel free to add an answer :)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ I know little software is being developed for Python versions less than 2.6. I am making a script, and if pip isn't installed, the script will install it for you via downloading get-pip.py and running it. If your version of python is incompatible with pip, instead a message will be output. Trivial, yes. Wanted by me, also yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official installation documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#python-os-support):

> **Python & OS Support**
>
> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and also pypy.

Comment: Is there a reason it doesn't work with 3.0 / 3.1? @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ

Comment: why are you using 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I'm not. I just wanted to make sure, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629708/what-versions-of-python-does-pip-support/31629807#comment51207343_31629708)